# Do any archive manager programs allow browsing hidden files in .iso's?

Tags: windows, file-management, file-compression

I am on Windows 7 and looking for a tool to view hidden files inside ISO images.  I have tried two archive packages (WinRAR and 7-Zip) and have tried mounting the image but to no avail. What should should I be using?

My images are of DVD-ROMs and the files are marked as hidden for copyright reasons.

I know the files are hidden because the displayed files only add up to 8 kB while the ISO itself is 2.3 GB.

Comment: Hidden how? Using the hidden NTFS flag? On what filesystem?

Comment: What kind of ISO is this?

Comment: How you know they are hidden? What kind of files are you looking for?

Comment: @Braiam I think it's safe to assume this is an ISO9660 file system.

Comment: Wow, are you sure you are up against "hidden files" and not trying to reverse engineer some cloak and dagger type stuff that is some corporation's idea of security? We may not be able to recommend something without knowing exactly what crazy stunt has been pulled with your discs.

Comment: ISO 9660 doesn't define any concept of hidden file. Some “copy protection” mechanisms work by making invalid filesystems where the data can only be read in some peculiar way. There is no generic solution to extract data from such invalid filesystems. What you need here is not a generic tool (there can't be one) but some custom help reverse engineering this particular image. The first step would be to precisely identify the disk image and see if others have already done the work.

Comment: You can head over to [Reverse Engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) to see if they can help you there.